# Would a JWT token be cross compatible between frameworks?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, go, jwt

If I have a JWT token generated by a ruby-on-rails application, would it be possible to decrypt that token in another framework/language like go?

This is assuming the JWT token is using the same algorithm and secret key etc.

Comment: yes it is compatible

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to decode your token if the framework respects the https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519.